# Null pointer when creating object on click

Tags: c#, wpf

I keep having null pointer exception when i add to header.headerItems.Add(d2); in which my headerItems is an observable collection of type Data

Anyone can tell me why is this ?

```
 private void addData(Header header)
 {
        Data d2 = new Data("pol");
        header.headerItems.Add(d2);
 }
```

my Method which call this method is just as below. In which header is part of a Packet class.

```
addData(packet.header);
```

My header class

```
public class Header
    {
    private ObservableCollection<Data> headerCollection;
    private String sheadervalue;
    public Header(String headervalue)
    {
        sheadervalue = headervalue;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Data> headerItems
    { get { return headerCollection; } }

    public string headervalue
    {
        get { return sheadervalue; }
        set { sheadervalue = headervalue; }
    }
}
```

My data class

```
  public class Data
{
    private String sDatavalue;

    public Data(String datavalue)
    {
        this.sDatavalue = datavalue;

    }

    public string datavalue
    {
        get { return sDatavalue; }
        set { sDatavalue = datavalue; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that `packet.header` is initialized? Where does the value come from?

Comment: If you need more help give us more informations because we don't know anything else. You should post part of packet class maybe.

Comment: oh i forgot to include what it means. as edited as above. Yup that header is initialized already.

Comment: Check if headerItems is initialized then.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? The exception will contain a Stack Trace, this would be the best place to start looking IMO

Comment: I forgot to initialize it haha ops! thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is you accessing field of null object (header). do as below

```
private void addData(Header header)
 {
    if(null == header)
    {
       // if header null what you can do... e.g log header is null 
       return; 
    }
    if(null == header.headerItems)
    {
        header.headerItems = ....; // create new header item collection 
    }

    Data d2 = new Data("pol");
    header.headerItems.Add(d2);
 }
```

Comment: Yes right, since we don't have specification of what the code should do, this is allowed too :) lol

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti :) requirements are beyond the imagination. totally based on assumptions.

Comment: @UnhandledException lol :) yes, you were more luky with the assumption, it's like playing poker online in this way :) totally random :) lol.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the parameter header is null.
As the code is, right now, we don't have idea why parameter header is null.

Check with the debugger if packet.header is null, and if so, check why.

Possible cause, you forgot to initialize it in the constructor.
Other possible cause, you forgot to set the value of header somewhere.

Other possible cause, the problem is header.headerItems.
If header is not null, headerItems may be null.
Check it, check if it was initialized correctly in header constructor or where it must be initialized.

Why you are not using the debugger?
With the debugger you can see the state of each variable.